# Minorities and Prejudice.

Tags: politics, religion, discrimination

I watched an episode of Real Time with Bill Maher Show and 
made me wondering:
If you are majority (race, gender, caste or whatever) you always have to watch what you say about minorities otherwise you are called prejudice. But in many instances I have seen minorities saying whatever they feel like about a particular situation or person(s), etc. which is fine but my question is - 
Is this because you are always right if you are minority? and you have to support them as they are minority?

Comment: Welcome to Skeptics.SE! Please add a notable reference for your claim on  Minorities and Prejudice to meet the quality standards of this community as mentioned here-http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions. For additional information, kindly refer this link on how to ask a question in this community-http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/help/asking.